# Error when calling Java code in Grails

Tags: java, grails

I have issues with calling the java class from grails application.

Controller class:

```
class MyController{

    def index() { 
         somepkg.MyJavaClass.method()
    }
}
```

Java class:

```
package somepkg;

public class MyJavaClass{

    public void method() {
           // ... some logic here
    }
}
```

The error:

> No signature of method:
>   static somepkg.MyJavaClass.method() is applicable for argument types:
>   () values: [] Possible solutions: wait(), any(), find(), wait(long),
>   each(groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: Somehow you don't mention what the problem is so it's hard to help you. One thing is on my mind though - are you aware of the fact that object have to be created before you can call it's method?

Comment: I just forgot - but now is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a method of a class without creating an instance, the method has to be marked static:

```
public static void afada() throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
  PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("ediOrder.txt", "UTF-8");
  writer.println("a");
  writer.close();
}
```

or you have to create an instance first:

```
new examplepkg.testing().afada()
```